# How to access JMX interface in docker container on VM from outside?

Tags: java, docker, jmx, jmxtrans

I am trying to remotely monitor a JVM running in docker. The configuration looks like this:

machine: runs a JVM (in my case, Hello-World springboot app) in docker on an ubuntu machine (VM);
the IP of this machine is 10.10.1.29;
docker container has IP 172.28.0.3;
and to connect to VM by ssh I putted my creds

I have DockerFile of myApp

```
// some docker commands 

EXPOSE 9010
CMD ["java", \
 "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote", \
 "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false", \
 "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false", \
 "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010", \
 "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9010", \
 "-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=10.10.1.29", \
 "-jar /app/myApp-1.0.0.jar"]
```

the container starts and everything is super by docker-compose

config docker-compose.yaml:

```
// some yaml config
 
    ports:
      - "9010:9010" # JMX
```

I am running jconsole locally and tried to run this

```
service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://10.10.1.29:9010/jmxrmi
```

but connection failed

I tried different options but unfortunately unsuccessfully

Does anyone have a solution to this? Maybe the configuration is incorrect?

Comment: Did you publish the port? Can you please add the command you are using to run the container.

Comment: I'm using  docker-compose down && docker-compose up -d

Answer (score 0):

You will have to look into several issues here:

- run the JVM with JMX enabled. Be aware of the port that is opened to access these values
- run the docker container such that the port to the outside of the container
- as the container is running inside some OS ensure there is no firewall preventing access to this port from outside the OS
- as the OS is running inside a VM ensure that VM is fowarding traffic to the correct port
- from outside the VM access the correct interface/port. If this access is from outside the host OS, ensure the host OS does not implement a firewall and forwards the traffic correctly

Failure on any of these points will simply not give you access.